# Output Runtime error caused by executable run by execvp

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to execute c program executable using `execvp`. Normal cases like taking input using `scanf` and displaying output using `printf` works fine in terminal.
But Runtime errors are not displayed in terminal like `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
Here is my code :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
int fd=open("/dev/ptmx",O_RDWR);
char *name=ptsname(fd);
grantpt(fd);
unlockpt(fd);
  int pid=fork();
  if(pid==0){
    fd=open(name,O_RDWR);//opening pts
      if(fd<0){
        printf("fd error2\n");
        return -1;
      }
    char *cmd="./e"; //e is executable with runtime error 
    char *argv[2]={cmd,0};
    if(execvp(cmd,argv)<0)
    printf("execvp errorrr\n");

  }
  else{
    while(wait(0)!=pid);
    printf("Program exited\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried setting stderror using `dup2`. It didn't work.

Comment: What `fd` is used for when opened second time?

Comment: Does `./e` alone works?

Comment: fd is overwritten ones you get ptsname. because not needed anymore

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes It gives Segmentation fault as expected

Comment: That message is printed by the shell when the process it executes terminates with an error. If your program is exec'ing a program, it needs to check the reason why it terminated and print appropriate messages.

Comment: It can get this information by using the status argument to `wait()`.

Comment: OK, I guess I did not understand the question

Comment: Take a look at the macros that are used with the status from `wait()`, like `WIFSIGNALED()` and `WTERMSIG()`

Comment: @Barmar You are Right thank you.

Comment: @Barmar I get status 139 which googled and found that it maps to seg fault

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  When asking about a runtime problem, please post code that (cleanly) compiles

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care, but us humans do) 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding; `int pid=fork();`  The function: `fork()` has three different kinds of returned values: 1) >0 means in the parent process.  2) ==0 means in the child process  3) <0 means an error occurred.   The posted code only checks for two of those conditions

Comment: regarding; `int fd=open("/dev/ptmx",O_RDWR);`  Always check (>=0) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (<0) then call `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`..

Comment: regarding: `char *argv[2]={cmd,0};`  This is hiding the `argv[]` parameter in the `main()` signature statement.

Comment: regarding: `if(execvp(cmd,argv)<0)
        printf("execvp errorrr\n");`  the `exec` family of functions do not return unless there was an error.  Suggest: `execvp( cmd, argv );
        perror("execvp failed");  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the posted code fails to 'cleanup' after itself.  Namely, closing the open files before exiting the program.

Comment: regarding; `while(wait(0)!=pid);`  There is only a single child process, so no need for a `while()` loop.  Suggest:  `int status = wait( NULL );  if( status == --1 ) { // handle error }`

Comment: @user3629249 Ok got it! Thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the status argument to `wait()` to get the reason why the program exited.

```
int status;
while (wait(&status) != pid) {}
if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    printf("%s", strsignal(WTERMSIG(status)));
    if (WCOREDUMP(status)) {
        printf(" (core dumped)\n");
    } else {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```